# vuex: mapActions with custom parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Can I pass params to `vuex` actions from `data` properties from a component where the `vuex` actions have been mapped using `mapActions`?

For example `someValue` should be passed the action `add` via the mapped actions:

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
...
data: function() {
      return {
        someValue: ''
      }
    },
methods: mapActions([
  'add'
])
```

Answer (score -2):

`<input @model="someValue" v-on:keyup="add(someValue)" type="text" />` did the trick for me.